# Xamarin Android POSTing to WebAPI

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have a WebAPI service running on a server, and I am able to hit against it all day long in an MVC app I have.  I am now trying to create an Xamarin Android app that also hits against the same WebAPI.  I put together some code in a console app to test, and it works just fine.  However, when I put the same code in my Xamarin Android app, it cannot connect to the service, I get back an aggregate exception that basically wraps a WebException. Digging into the exception further, it seems it is a System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure type of error.

Here is the code:

```
 using (HttpClient webAPI = new HttpClient())
 {
        // hardcode the request to try and see why it errors
        AuthUserRequest thisUser = new AuthUserRequest
        {
            UserName = "username",
            Password = "password",
            AppName = "Dashboard"
        };

        webAPI.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thisUser);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        try
        {
            response = await webAPI.PostAsync("It'sOurURL", content);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            string sHold = err.Message;
            throw;
        }

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Context thisContext = Application.Context;
            Toast toast = Toast.MakeText(thisContext, "Successful", ToastLength.Short);
            toast.Show();
        }
    }
```

As I said it's weird it works just fine from a Console app, just not the Xamarin Android app.  Any insight at all into this?

Comment: can you connect to the url from the device/emulator browser?

Comment: Not to that specific URL since it needs a json object posted to it, but there is a get method in the same controller that I can hit just fine via the phones browser.  [EDIT] I had checked the URL and it was fine this morning, but now for whatever reason it is no longer available.  UGH... Never mind this question please...

Answer (score 0):

All looks pretty good. My API calls are working in Xamarin Android and iOS. My code is pretty much the same with two real minor differences. I have set ConfigureAwait(false) on the PostAsync call. Additionally I have created a URI variable with the address for the API endpoint and passed that into the PostAsync method, rather then using a hard coded string.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var user = new CredentialsModel
    {
        Password = password,
        Username = username,
    };

    var uri = new Uri("YOUR_URL_GOES_HERE");
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var authData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseModel>(responseContent);

        return authData;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It was my own bone-headed mistake... When I tried the URL this morning, it was there, but the IT department has been mucking about with the server, so it's no longer available externally.  Sorry to bother everyone with this.